# ZK Binding Issue With String Variable?

Tags: java, binding, zk

As i am trying to bind Few ZK Components like **Doublebox**  and **Decimalbox** with a **String**  variable

```
package com.viewmodel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.AfterCompose;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextParam;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextType;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;

import com.binding.BindComponent;

public class BindingViewModel {
    BindComponent compo = null;
    private List<BindComponent> dataList;

    @AfterCompose
    public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view){
        dataList = new ArrayList<BindComponent>();
        compo = new BindComponent();
        compo.setDecimalbox("12.67");
        compo.setTextbox("hariom");
        compo.setDoublebox("123");
        compo.setIntbox(12);
        dataList.add(compo);

    }

    public BindComponent getCompo() {
        return compo;
    }
    public void setCompo(BindComponent compo) {
        this.compo = compo;
    }
    public List<BindComponent> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }
    public void setDataList(List<BindComponent> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }


}
```

And the ZUl page..

```
<?page title="Auto Generated index.zul"?>
<window title="Hello World!!" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
    border="normal" width="200px"
    viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.viewmodel.BindingViewModel')">

    <label value="You are using: ${desktop.webApp.version}" />

    <listbox model="@bind(vm.dataList)">
        <listhead>
            <listheader value="Textbox"></listheader>
            <listheader value="DoubleBox"></listheader>
            <listheader value="IntBox"></listheader>
            <listheader value="DecimalBox"></listheader>

        </listhead>
        <template name="model" var="mymodel">
            <listitem>
                <listcell>
                    <textbox value="@bind(mymodel.textbox)"></textbox>
                </listcell>
                <listcell>
                    <doublebox value="@bind(mymodel.doublebox)"></doublebox>
                </listcell>
                <listcell>
                    <intbox value="@bind(mymodel.intbox)"></intbox>
                </listcell>
                <listcell>
                    <decimalbox value="@bind(mymodel.decimalbox)"></decimalbox>
                </listcell>
            </listitem>
        </template>
    </listbox>
</window>
```

And Bean Class....

```
public class BindComponent {
    private String textbox;
    private int intbox;
    private String doublebox;
    private String decimalbox;
    public String getTextbox() {
        return textbox;
    }
    public void setTextbox(String textbox) {
        this.textbox = textbox;
    }
    public int getIntbox() {
        return intbox;
    }
    public void setIntbox(int intbox) {
        this.intbox = intbox;
    }
    public String getDoublebox() {
        return doublebox;
    }
    public void setDoublebox(String doublebox) {
        this.doublebox = doublebox;
    }
    public String getDecimalbox() {
        return decimalbox;
    }
    public void setDecimalbox(String decimalbox) {
        this.decimalbox = decimalbox;
    }



}
```

Now the issue is that when i am going to change value in zul page set method is not called because i am binding zul values with a String variable. Can any one tell me what is the issue with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is [`Decimalbox#getValue()`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Decimalbox.html#getValue%28%29) returns a [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)
The solution should be

```
public void setDecimalbox(BigDecimal decimalbox) {
    this.decimalbox = decimalbox != null ? decimalbox.toString() : this.decimalbox;
}
```

And for [`Doublebox`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Doublebox.html#getValue%28%29)

```
public void setDoublebox(Double doublebox) {
    this.doublebox = doublebox != null ? doublebox.toString : this.doublebox;
}
```

Comment: Nabil i am talking about doublebox and decimal box not intbox..only these component bind from String varaible then it creating issue

Comment: Can you explain the error a bit more. I think I don't get you right.

Comment: actually as i mentioned in question when i am going to bind doulebox and decimalbox with a String variable and when i put some value in doublebox or decimalbox set method is not called so value in not updated in java code

Comment: Ok do you mean by we can not bind decimal box with String variable?

Comment: As I understand zk, if you bind, zk calls `mySetter(Component.getValue())` so the setter must accept, what is returned by `getValue()`.